# LoadMenu loads a menu which looks very outdated

Tags: c++, winapi, menu

I'm using this code in VS2012 to load a menu from a resource file of my .exe app. I am on Windows 7;

> m_hMenu = LoadMenu(lpApplication->m_hInstance, lpszMenuName);

I'm then passing the m_hMenu as a handle to CreateWindow. My application, I believe, has the correct manifest (other controls have nice styling):

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
```

This is what my application's menu looks like:

[image]

This is what the menu in Notepad.exe looks like:

[image]

My applications menu seems to look "old" and I can't figure out why. I need someone to point me in the right direction to theming my menu to have the translucent hover/styling like shown in the second picture.

Comment: Are you doing any owner draw in your menu? That will disable the themed appearance.

Comment: No, I'm not doing any custom drawing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, setting the "Break" parameter to "Bar" under the menu designer causes the menu to revert to older styling. I didn't think this would be relevant.